# Creating multiple random numpy arrays with different range of values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I got a question so I was trying to create a 3D array containing multiple 2D array with different range of values, for example I can do this:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)

arr = np.random.randint(1, 10, size = (2,2)) #Random 2D array with range of values (1, 10)
arr2 = np.random.randint(11, 20, size = (2,2)) #Random 2D array with range of values (11, 20)
...
```

and then create the 3D array by this

```
newarr = np.array([arr, arr2, ...])
```

I try doing this:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)

n = 3

aux = []

for i in range (n):
    if i == 0:
        aux.append(rng4.randint(1, 10, size = (2, 2)))
    elif i == 1:
        aux.append(rng4.randint(11, 20, size = (2, 2)))
    elif i == 2:
        aux.append(rng4.randint(21, 30, size = (2, 2)))

newarr = np.array(aux)
```

The output is what I want but in either case if I want another range of values I need to "add" manually a new `elif` to give another range, is there a way I can do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a trivial loop programming exercise:

```
newarr = np.empty(shape=(2, 2, n))
for i in range (n):
    newarr[:,:,i] = rng4.randint(i * 10 + 1, i * 10 + 10,
                                 size = (2, 2))
```

Comment: The second edit was great! This last one the output it's a 3D array with shape (2, 2, 3)  not exactly what I need, but the other one help me! Thank you!